# Conjoint() function in R

Tags: r, data-mining, data-analysis

I have a problem with the output of the conjoint function.
I have 5 attributes with 3 leveles on each attribute, but in the output, started with the second attribute on the third level, the result is NA and I don't know what can I do to fix the problem.
Here my code and the result of conjoint function (img. Output conjoint function).

Can you help me, please?

```
alimentatie<-c("mancare gatita","fast food","amandoua in mod alternativ") 

activitati<-c("regulat","de cateva ori pe luna","foarte rar")

bauturi<-c("evit cat de mult pot","oricat de des simt nevoia","ocazional")

odihna<-c("7-8 ore","4-6 ore","mai mult de 8 ore")

Recreere<-c("3-6","mai mult de 6","mai putin de 3")

factor_levels<-as.data.frame(c(alimentatie,activitati,bauturi,odihna,recreere))

colnames(factor_levels)<-"levels"

data<-expand.grid(alimentatie,activitati,bauturi,odihna,recreere)

colnames(data)<-c("Alimentatie","Activitati","Bauturi","Odihna","Recreere")


facdesign_full<-caFactorialDesign(data = data, type = "full")

encdesign_full<-caFactorialDesign(facdesign_full)


response<-read.table("cc.txt", sep="\t",header = T)
response<-as.data.frame(response)


conjoint_analysis<-Conjoint(response,encdesign_full,factor_levels)
```

I coded each answer (a total of 59 answers) for the 5 questions with the values ​​"0 1 and 2" as:

```
Alimentatie: "mancare gatita" code 0, "fast food" code 1 ,"amandoua in mod alternativ" code 2; 
Activitati: "regulat" code 0,"de cateva ori pe luna" code 1,"foarte rar" code 2; 
Bauturi: "evit cat de mult pot" code 0,"oricat de des simt nevoia" code 1 ,"ocazional" code 2; 
Odihna: "7-8 ore" code 0,"4-6 ore" code 1,"mai mult de 8 ore" code 2;
Recreere: "3-6" code 0,"mai mult de 6" code 1,"mai putin de 3" code  2
```

I attached a photo (Data) with a part of the cc.csv file (because the txt file appears offset).

Data:
[Data Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Co2rm0QQiqHOXIUeu7TivevJCqCAwtzx)

```
dput(rasps)
structure(list(`Profil 1` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L), `Profil 2` = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), `Profil 3` = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
2L), `Profil 4` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L
), `Profil 5` = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 59L))
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Znd.png)

After updated the code:

[After Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyIjL.png)

Output conjoint function:

[image: Output conjoint function]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! At present it's challenging to troubleshoot your problem because we do not have access to your ```cc.txt``` file. It would make thing a lot easier if you could add that file, or some simulated data in the body of your question. Have a look at this help center (page) [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] to get a better idea of what I am suggesting.

Comment: Also, based on how your code is presented, I get an error at the ```factor_levels``` line because the ```Recreere``` object uses a capitalized R, while the factor levels line uses ```recreere``` in lower case. Please edit your question to correct this typo.

Comment: I corrected the code, I wrote in lower case that object. Also, I added a part of my data which represent the codification of the survey's answers. I hope now is better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code calls the `caFactorialDesign` function twice, on two consecutive lines. Yet according to a `conjoint` [vignette](http://keii.ue.wroc.pl/conjoint/Conjoint_R.html), `caEncodedDesign` is

> the function [that] encodes the factorial design obtained using
>   caFactorialDesign function for the needs of conjoint module
>   functioning

Based on this, I believe one issue seems to be that your second `caFactorialDesign` call is incorrect. You should probably instead call `caEncodedDesign` to generate the`encdesign_full` object.  So try adjusting your code to:

```
    # replace the line encdesign_full <- caFactorialDesign(facdesign_full) with
    encdesign_full <- caEncodedDesign(facdesign_full)
```

Also, here is your code re-written is a more compact and reproducible fashion:

```
    # load library
    library(conjoint)

    # combinations of levels
    data <- expand.grid(
      alimentatie = c("mancare gatita","fast food","amandoua in mod alternativ"), 
      activitati = c("regulat","de cateva ori pe luna","foarte rar"),
      bauturi = c("evit cat de mult pot","oricat de des simt nevoia","ocazional"),
      odihna = c("7-8 ore","4-6 ore","mai mult de 8 ore"),
      recreere = c("3-6","mai mult de 6","mai putin de 3"))

    # profile
    facdesign_full <- caFactorialDesign(data = data, type = "full")
    profile <- caEncodedDesign(facdesign_full)

    # level names
    levelnames <- data.frame(
      levels = c("mancare gatita","fast food","amandoua in mod alternativ",
      "regulat","de cateva ori pe luna","foarte rar","evit cat de mult pot",
      "oricat de des simt nevoia","ocazional", "7-8 ore","4-6 ore",
      "mai mult de 8 ore","3-6","mai mult de 6","mai putin de 3")
  )
# preferences
    response <- structure(list(alimentatie = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
      0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
      2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
      2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
      2L, 0L, 1L), activitati = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
      0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
      2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
      2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      2L, 2L), bauturi = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
      1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
      2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
      2L), odihna = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
      0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), 
      recreere = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
      2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
      0L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -59L))
```

Notice that by specifying a "full" design, the `profile` object has 243 rows, while your `response` object has only 59:

```
dim(profile)
[1] 243 5
dim(response)
[1] 59 5
```

This seems to confuse the `Conjoint` function, I presume because it is looking for 243 rows of data in the `response` object.

In fact, if you append 184 rows of simulated data to the `response` object, `Conjoint` seems to produce the desired result:

```
    # simulated response data
    set.seed(1)
    response_sim <- data.frame(alimentatie = sample(0:2, 184, replace = T),
      activitati = sample(0:2, 184, replace = T),
      bauturi = sample(0:2, 184, replace = T),
      odihna = sample(0:2, 184, replace = T),
      recreere = sample(0:2, 184, replace = T))

    # append simulated preferences
    response_n243 <- rbind(response, response_sim)

    # run 
    Conjoint(response_n243,profile, levelnames)
```

[image: Console image]

**Conclusion**

Your issue appears to result from having less data in your `response` object than is required to run a "full" factorial design. It seems like you may need to provide more `response` data, or re-consider your design, with special attention given to the `type` argument of `caFactorialDesign`. A "fractional" design might be an alternative.

Comment: I tried to apply what you said, but the problem persists. I attached a print screen in the original message (After Update img.)

Comment: Could you provide us with the full data of the ```response``` object (or the ```rasps``` object )? This could be achieved by copy-pasting the console output of the code ```dput(response)``` or ```dput(rasps)``` into the body of your question.

Comment: Done. Also, I added on google drive the data into two formats of files .csv & .txt (cc1.csv and cc.txt). [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Co2rm0QQiqHOXIUeu7TivevJCqCAwtzxhttps://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Co2rm0QQiqHOXIUeu7TivevJCqCAwtzx)

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right, the problem was that the number of profiles was higher than the number of responses, so I used a fractional design with 59 profiles. I managed to do the conjoint analysis.`facdesign_fractional<-caFactorialDesign(data = data, type = "fractional",cards = 59)
profile<-caEncodedDesign(facdesign_fractional)`